# Bootstrap carousel after last slide the height is changing

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, bootstrap-carousel

I have used bootstrap 3 carousel and i have 3 slides in my banner and I have three background images in each item.I have activated auto sliding using `data-ride="carousel"` and now after last slide the carousel height is changing a jumping is showing up. How can I correct these bug???

[Live Demo](http://zillioni.com/demo/apco/)

My code

```
<div class="banner">

<section id="main-slider" class="no-margin">
        <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

            <div class="carousel-inner">

                <div class="item active" style="background-image: url(images/slider/bg1.jpg)">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row slide-margin">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="carousel-content">
                                    <h1 class="animation animated-item-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</h1>
                                    <h2 class="animation animated-item-2">Accusantium doloremque laudantium totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa...</h2>
                                    <a class="btn-slide animation animated-item-3" href="#">Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-6 hidden-xs animation animated-item-4">
                                <div class="slider-img">
                                    <img src="images/slider/img1.png" class="img-responsive">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!--/.item-->



                <div class="item" style="background-image: url(images/slider/bg3.jpg)">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row slide-margin">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="carousel-content">
                                    <h1 class="animation animated-item-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</h1>
                                    <h2 class="animation animated-item-2">Accusantium doloremque laudantium totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa...</h2>
                                    <a class="btn-slide animation animated-item-3" href="#">Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6 hidden-xs animation animated-item-4">
                                <div class="slider-img">
                                    <img src="images/slider/img3.png" class="img-responsive">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!--/.item-->

                <div class="item" style="background-image: url(images/slider/bg2.jpg)">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row slide-margin">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="carousel-content">
                                    <h1 class="animation animated-item-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</h1>
                                    <h2 class="animation animated-item-2">Accusantium doloremque laudantium totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa...</h2>
                                    <a class="btn-slide animation animated-item-3" href="#">Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-6 hidden-xs animation animated-item-4">
                                <div class="slider-img">

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!--/.item-->


            </div><!--/.carousel-inner-->
        </div><!--/.carousel-->
        <a class="prev hidden-xs" href="#main-slider" data-slide="prev">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="next hidden-xs" href="#main-slider" data-slide="next">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
        </a>
    </section><!--/#main-slider-->




</div>
```

Comment: I noticed looking at your website when your slides are transitioning for a brief second these classes are being added then removed: item next left active. One of those class could be over writing your slide classes causing the jump. I'd look there first

Comment: Are all the images are of same height?

Comment: @reddy Yes same height

Comment: My problem is solved. I had set `min-heght` and `height` to carousel-inner class, I don't know this is a best practice. But my client is happy and the jumping issue is not showing up now. Thanks for your timely support.

Answer (score 0):

Set `min-height` and `height` to carousel-inner class. The height should be the same as banner height.